Problem with Looker Studio Control Filters and Data Visualization
Let's consider this table has my DataBase:



City
Age
Name
Phone




Lisbon
33
Tom
123


Lisbon
23
Liam
351


Madrid
42
Mike
456


Madrid
34
Dan
231


Berlin
56
John
789


Berlin
31
Ken
234



I have added 3 Control Filters and a Chart to my Dashboard.
One filter controls "City", another controls "Age" and the last one controls "Name".
The Chart is simply used to display the Phone number.
Problem:
Once I select a value on the first filter, the remaining filters get selected as well, instead of remaining blank and waiting for the user to choose a value.
Example: If on the first filter I select "Lisbon", filter 2 will automatically be checked with all the possible values, in this case, "33" and "23" and the Chart will show a Phone Number (depending on the sorting configuration).
Basically what I need 2 things:
-> Filter 2 and Filter 3 should not be automatically checked w/ all the possible values, once Filter 1 is selected.
-> The Chart should only show a value (in this case, Phone number), once all the Filters have been applied by the user

